# Power configuration for docked - undocked laptop

Tags: windows-7, power-management, docking-station

I have a problem with my power configuration for my laptop. I have a laptop (Dell E-6530) which I use for work at home and at office. At office I also have a docking station (Dell E-Port Plus II) with my monitors, ethernet, etc.

The problem is that I dock it with the lid closed, so I need to configure it to "do nothing" on lid close, but I would like the laptop to sleep when I close the lid and it's not docked? Is there any way to accomplish that? I googled a lot, but only thing I found are old references to some "Hardware profiles" which no longer exist in Win 7.

Comment: The lid close action can be changed from a scheduled task, but the problem is how to check whether the laptop is currently docked or not. Are there any events in the event log during docking/undocking?

Comment: A possible solution is to not close the lid completely when docking, or change the layout of your desk and use the laptop screen as another monitor for a multiple monitor setup.